# Unable to access GRUb2 menu neither the BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub, bios

I have an ASUS with dual boot (ubuntu 16.04 and Windows10) for a while. These days it happens that the PC boot directly into linux. I tried all the possible solutions (start button/escape key , Start/shift, start/up arrow) , even start/F2 to access BIOS don't work.
I changed my grub configuration file on /etc/defaults to these setting and the problem persists

> Blockquote

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

File `/etc/defaults/grub` is not changing actual configuration of grub.

Defaults file is being used when you issue `grub2-mkconfig` command to create an actual grub configuration file which resides in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` or similar location (you may need to mount actual boot partition depending on your system configuration).

Before changing anything backup your actual grub.cfg file so you can restore it (i.e. booting rescue system from pendrive) if something goes wrong and your machine will not boot properly.

Comment: I tried the grub-mkconfig, it didn't solve the problem. The update-grub command gives me this :
Création du fichier de configuration GRUB…

Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-186-generic

Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-186-generic
Image Linux trouvée : /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-185-generic

Image mémoire initiale trouvée : /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-185-generic

Windows Boot Manager trouvé sur /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration

fait

Comment: @Dodilila: Could you post your `lsblk` command result. Is there enough space on your efi partition? Are you actually using EFI and not MBR?

Comment: I am using EFI, here is the lsblk command result:
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931,5G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0  69,7G  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   3,7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb5   8:21   0   499M  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0  45,1G  0 part /